# New-ItemProperty not "commiting" during scripted creation of a website

Tags: powershell, iis

We use a [blue-green](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/BlueGreenDeployment.html) deployment philosophy to deploy our applications and have invested heavily in PS scripting the creation and configuration of our IIS websites.

Most recently we updated our scripts to configure IIS logging to include the value of a custom header using `New-ItemProperty`. However we have seen situations where this command doesn't seem to "commit" (for want of a better word) the change to IIS and the configuration fails silently.

Here is a simplified version of the script (including some other hacks that we had to adopt because WebAdministration).

```
Import-Module WebAdministration

$websiteName = "Product 1.0 App"
$aTargetLocation = "C:\Apps\Product\1.0\App"
$aAppPool = "App"
$httpPort = 8870

New-Website -Name "$websiteName" -PhysicalPath $aTargetLocation -ApplicationPool $aAppPool
Start-Sleep -s 3

Write-Host "Ensure site is stopped and stays stopped until explicitly started"
Stop-Website -Name "$websiteName"
Start-Sleep -s 1
Set-ItemProperty "IIS:\Sites\$websiteName" serverAutoStart False

Write-Host "Remove default port 80 binding that was added by default..."
Get-WebBinding -Port 80 -Name "$websiteName" | Remove-WebBinding
Start-Sleep -s 1

Write-Host "New web binding $websiteName -> Http Port $httpPort"
New-WebBinding -Name "$websiteName" -Port $httpPort -IPAddress *
Start-Sleep -s 1

Write-Host "Ensuring we log the CorrelationId in IIS logfiles"
New-ItemProperty "IIS:\Sites\$websiteName" -Name logfile.customFields.collection -Value `
    @{logFieldName='CorrelationId';sourceType='RequestHeader';sourceName='CorrelationId'}

Start-Sleep -s 1
```

So for some applications, this works a treat and the configuration of the `CorrelationId` header sticks.  For other sites it appears to consistently fail silently - no error, no event log nothing: the configuration just doesn't "commit" and we end up manually adding the header after deployment, which defeats the purpose of automation!

In attempting to debug this issue, I was able to repro for a number of attempts - but then the value appeared to "stick" and would never fail again: most frustrating.

Any tips/workarounds?

As an aside, I'm getting sick of the hacks that I have to do to use the powershell WebAdministration module in order to script creation of websites during deployment.  Here's a list of bitterness:

- [Start-Sleep required between commands](http://forums.iis.net/t/1191628.aspx)
- Concurrent access not supported, forcing us to use a system semaphore to "serialize" access to IIS
- net-tcp binding cannot be set during deployment, can only be done at start/stop time
- AppPool names must be less than 64 chars

Comment: We mostly use AppCmd in our scripting, and we often find that the applicationHost.config is somehow locked, for a small period of time, when doing commits of multiple settings consecutive - exactly like your "Start-Sleep required between commands" link.
You may want to look into that, try using Sysinternals Process Monitor to identify the precise problem.

Comment: Yep - we ran into that too, and now all our WebAdministration "conversations" are wrapped in a semaphore.WaitOne/Release block to prevent scripts running in parallel accessing IIS at the same time plus "sleeps" between commands..  But in this case we are not seeing anything like that.. The New-ItemProperty command is the last in the block, with an extended period of time until the next IIS interaction

Comment: Besides, if I go back to AppCmd I will cry. I may as well have written the script in good ole fashioned DOS Batch...